# What's the best practice to create new objects in C++?

Tags: c++, object, smart-pointers

I'm fairly new to C++ and just learned about smart pointers. Now I'm wondering what the best practice is to make sure that they are efficiently used (let's say my optimization algorithm requires hundreds of millions of objects to be created, evaluated [in `relatives`] and then then safely discarded - ideally in a concurrent way).

I would appreciate if you could tell me if this is alright or if there is something else I'm supposed to do differently/better.

**Edit:** This s a simplified example to focus on the correct creation of the objects. Obviously, simple properties could be represented differently. Here, I am trying to focus on learning how to correctly create objects that reference other objects and may be referenced by many other objects before they are destroyed. So my question is if the code below is a reasonably fast and, more important, safe way to create objects.

```
class Property {
public:
    int id;
};

class Pet {
    const int id_;
    const std::shared_ptr<Property> myProperty_;
    const std::shared_ptr<Property> myProperty2_;
    std::map<double, std::shared_ptr<Pet>> relatives;  // one of the places where the object will be referenced, I use "HashMap" in my Java prototype

    Pet(const int id, const std::shared_ptr<Property> myProperty, const std::shared_ptr<Property> myProperty2) : 
        id_(id), myProperty_(myProperty), myProperty2_(myProperty2) { }

    const std::shared_ptr<Pet> makePet(const int id, const std::shared_ptr<Property> myProperty, const std::shared_ptr<Property> myProperty2) {
        return std::make_shared<Pet>(id, myProperty, myProperty2);
    }
};
```

As I mentioned before, eventually I hope to be able to implement something so multiple threads can access `relatives`, but don't think this is relevant for the object creation (is it?).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need `shared_ptr`s? Do `Pet` objects really share the same value of the `myProperty_`/`2_` data members?

Comment: Don't use shared_ptr unless ownership is unclear or shared.

Comment: Note that `shared_ptr` is most costly pointer possible. What prevents you from using normal direct data members, e.g. `Property myProperty_`?

Comment: I guess he's trying to avoid duplicating the same property for millions of `Pet` objects, so he can have one "three leg" property for all of them. This could be worth it if the property is bigger than a shared pointer, though. (Which in the example isn't.)

Comment: "What's the best practice..." This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: Please note that this is a simplified example to focus on the object (I mistakenly thought I made that clear). Actually, the object are far more complex and contain values that have to be calculated. I'll update the OP.

Comment: `std::map<double...>` is somewhat suspicious as `double` is susject to rounding errors. Thus you have to be very careful on how you use it. You also need to ensure that you never put **NaN** in the container.

Comment: If multiple threads access your data, then creation is an important aspect as it make  huge difference if creation is done before concurrent accesses or not and what modifications are allowed and the granularity of concurrent access you need. **In C++, best solution is generally very specific and as such your question is to broad**.

Comment: If you really have hundreds of millions items, then you will probably wants to make some profiling if you have a performance or memory problem.

Comment: @Phil: Thank you for the replies. `map` was just an example. I realize now that the title is  indeed unfortunate, as I am currently trying to learn *smart pointers* and what to look out for. Most importantly, if the way I do it in the example code is safe and if there is anything I have look out for. For example, one downside I see right now is that if I delete that object, I also have to go through all the objects that reference it and delete those references. But I assume that can't be avoided.

Comment: Regarding profiling, I have no idea how to even approach this subject, so I guess this will have to wait until I have some more experience under my belt and finished the MVP.

Comment: What does the double in the map represent?

Comment: @Surt: It was just meant to demonstrate that I have an object with lots of references to other objects, which I need manage (create and destroy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of `std::shared_ptr` is so cool that I had to use it everywhere in my first new project after it appeared! It enables RAII (A C++ explicit garbage collection method) for all objects pointed to being destroyed when the object owning the `std::shared_ptr` is destroyed.

Now `std::shared_ptr` has a few drawbacks, some with the concept and some with the implementation.

- It is possible to make circular dependences that will leave the data unreferenced by the rest of the program, effectively leaking the memory.
- If there is only one logical owner, there is a simpler smart pointer, `std::unique_ptr`
- If there are none-owning references, raw pointers can be used instead. (the none-owners must be destroyed before the owning smart pointers)
- It introduces an extra indirection.

```cpp
    std::shared_ptr<Pet> pet;
```

```
pet->control block->Pet object
```

Which is an external reference count, as opposed to where the reference count is part of the object.

```
pet->Counter + Pet object
```

So if your goal is to delete a Pet when there are no more refences to it there are different methods to do it.

```
using PetId = int;
std::unordered_map<PetId, std::shared_ptr<Pet>> PetDict; // global pet owner, hash map/dictionary

void ErasePet(PetId id) {
  auto pet = PetDict.find(id);
  if (pet != PetDict.end()) // can be avoided if you know id is in PetDict ... no, you can't be sure.
    PetDict.erase(pet); // this is not enough as the relatives still keep the pet alive and will cause a dead pet to still have relations while not being findable anymore.
}
```

So before erasing the pet you will have to make the `relatives` forget the pet, there are at least three ways to do this

- change `relatives` to use `std::weak_ptr`

  - requires extra checking before using elements of `relatives` as the relation could have be erased.
- change `relatives` to use the `PetId` instead of the `std::shared_ptr<Pet>`

  - requires an extra lookup in PetDict each time before using elements of `relatives`as the relation could have be erased.
- iterate through the `relatives` to erase the relation in each of those.

  - as `relatives` is not indexed by `PetId`, all nodes of `relatives` must be check for the right `PetId`, rather horrible O(m) but then how often ar pets deleted?

The first two options are a kind of lazy delete as they can remove the relation once it is found that it is no longer active, though it will still cost in alive checking for every usage.

Regarding the thread safety, there are several variants.

- If you only read after creating the pets everything is fine
- If you change the reference count by making a copy of a `std::shared_ptr` that is also OK, as the counter is the only part of `std::shared_ptr` that is atomic.
- If you change the object that the `std::shared_ptr` points to in the control block, you get a race condition
- If you change the values of an object that the `std::shared_ptr` points to you get a race condition.

In C++20 [std::atomic(std::shared_ptr)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) can help with atomic updates of the control block, but you still needs to make access to the pointed to object thread safe yourself.
The usual cost benefits for how many readers/writes must be evaluated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! It is anticipating many of the questions that I also had. `weak_ptr`s indeed seem to make much more sense as members in this case. Furthermore, the example you give is much closer to what I actually want, so managing lots of relatives is definitely an issue. And multithreading will also become a problem for me, but one thing at a time. Thanks again!